# Two foreign keys to the same same table in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

If we would have two foreign keys, then how would create a QueryBuilder  like this SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mappaths m
JOIN unitids n ON (m.ref_unitids2 = n.id OR m.ref_unitids1 = n.id)
WHERE m.id = 2
```

For this I design like this QueryBuilder but I do not think it is correct:

```
$query = $qb->select('m')
    ->from('ApiMapBundle:Mappaths','m')
    ->innerJoin('m.refUnitids1','u')
    ->innerJoin('m.refUnitids2','v')   
    ->where('m.id=:test')
    ->setParameter('test',1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;

$users = $reposity->getResult();
return $users;

$dql = $qb->getDql();
echo $dql;
$result = $query->getResult();
echo $result;
```

Any idea how can I solve this above query using QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Your example will not work as both innerJoins have to be realised to return a row.

Something like this may work (I have not tested this):

```
$query = $qb->select('m')
    ->from('ApiMapBundle:Mappaths','m')
    ->join('YourBundle:YourOtherEntity', 'u', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->orX('m.refUnitids1 = u.id','m.refUnitids2 = u.id'))
    ->where('m.id=:test')
    ->setParameter('test',1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: jason.. one problem i have here with this query for example if I request for  table1(identity,a1,b1)
table2(identitiy,forign_a1,forign_a1)   with data table2(1,2,3) so it give me a values of sequence 2,3 and some cases it give 3,2. if they find second foriegn key first then it give me alternative way. any idea how to slove this issue... lookingforward for your help?